# Unforseen Dictionary behavior

Tags: c#

I ran into some curious behavior when using *C#* `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class. 
First a little introduction:

I have a definition of a class called AVariable:

```
public class AVariable
{
    public AType VarType { get; set; }

    public AObject Value { get; set; }

    public AVariable(AObject val, AType type)
    {
        VarType = type;
        Value = val;
    }
}
```

The following class takes care of these variables when inserting them into a Dictionary

```
public class VariablePool
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, AVariable> _runtimeVariableMap;

    public VariablePool()
    {
        _runtimeVariableMap = new Dictionary<string, AVariable>();
    }

    public void AddNewVariable(string name, AVariable vrb)
    {
        _runtimeVariableMap[name] = vrb;
    }

    public void DebugDump(TextWriter tw) // Just a demo for here
    { ... prints out stuff about variable...  }
}
```

This is how I use the mentioned classes:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var varPool = new VariablePool();
    varPool.AddNewVariable("a", new AVariable(new ANumeric(120), AType.ANumeric));
    varPool.AddNewVariable("b", new AVariable(new ANumeric(130), AType.ANumeric));
    varPool.AddNewVariable("c", new AVariable(new AString("Hello"), AType.AString));
    varPool.AddNewVariable("d", new AVariable(new AString("World"), AType.AString));
    varPool.DebugDump(Console.Out);
    Console.Read();
}
```

EDIT: The A[Type] hierarchy

```
public class AObject
{
}

public class AString : AObject
{
    private static string _rawStr;

    public AString(string str)
    {
        _rawStr = str;
    }

    public AString(AString str)
    {
        _rawStr = str.GetRawValue();
    }

    public string GetRawValue()
    {
        return _rawStr;
    }
}

public class ANumeric : AObject
{
    private static double _rawVal;

    public ANumeric(double val)
    {
        _rawVal = val;
    }

    public ANumeric(ANumeric num)
    {
        _rawVal = num.GetRawValue();
    }

    public double GetRawValue()
    {
        return _rawVal;
    }
}
```

What I expect to be the output of `DebugDump`:

```
Name: a
Type: ANumeric
Value: 120

Name: b
Type: ANumeric
Value: 130


Name: c
Type: AString
Value: Hello

Name: d
Type: AString
Value: World
```

What actually happens:

```
Name: a
Type: ANumeric
Value: 130

Name: b
Type: ANumeric
Value: 130

Name: c
Type: AString
Value: World


Name: d
Type: AString
Value: World
```

My question is simple: Why does that happen? Why is the last `Value` applied to *all* the variables of same type?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
GetRawValue() returns a private member that is assigned in constructor.

Comment: Don't think I have ever seen a property-backed property. You could just say `public AType VarType { get; private set; }`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET `dic[x] = y` is valid - it just adds or overwrites

Comment: I can't see anything either - can you post `GetRawValue()`?

Comment: It doesn't help that we can't reproduce the problem without `AType` and `AObject`. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Also, you can reduce your `AVariable` code dramatically by just using automatically implemented properties rather than having one property calling another.

Comment: Is anything static? If the field that gets written to in the ANumeric or AString constructors was static, you'd see this behavior since you'd be overwriting the same static field from different objects' constructors.

Comment: Please show the definitions of AObject, AString, ANumeric and AType.

Comment: Based on the behavior, it is practically guaranteed that the code you posted isn't the code that's executing. You're reusing the instance of something somewhere; either the value objects (ANumeric and AString), or the AVariable type isn't actually immutable and you're reusing those instances. As everyone else says, post an actual code example, and keep it minimal please (i.e. the least amount of code required to demonstrate the issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the static here:

```
private static string _rawStr
```

And read about [static classes and static members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx), especially:

> Only one copy of a static member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are created.

Comment: I don't feel very smart right now. That solved the problem. Thanks.